# Replace and Association

Tags: replacement, associations

I'm surprised that I can't find this question already, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious. I would like to take a list of associations and remove any with value `"red"`. I ran into the following problem:

```
{<|8 -> 7|>, <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|>} /. <|"a" -> "red", s___|> :> Nothing
```

outputs

```
{<|8 -> 7|>, <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|>}
```

rather than my expected

```
{<|8 -> 7|>}
```

However,

```
{<|8 -> 7|>, <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|>} /. <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|> :> Nothing
```

works as expected, to give `{<|8 -> 7|>}`. It's as if `Association` is applying `Verbatim` or something.

Why does the replacement fail here? Of course, the corresponding version using lists instead of associations works.

Comment: Funnily enough: `MatchQ[Association["a" -> "red", 6 -> 3], 
 Association["a" -> "red", __]]` returns `False`. (For comparison, replacing `Association[]` with `List[]` gives `True`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Associations are funny beasts -- neither fish nor fowl. Sometimes they are treated as atomic expressions and sometime they are not. For pattern matching purposes their atomic nature seems to rule. Consider this far more elementary case.

```
a = <|"a" -> 2|>;
AtomQ @ a
```

> `True`

Any expression can be used as a pattern and always matches itself.

```
MatchQ[a, <|"a" -> 2|>]
```

> `True`

But other than this trivial case, no pattern based the form of `a` matches `a`. All of

```
MatchQ[a, <|_ -> 2|>]
MatchQ[a, <|"a" -> _|>]
MatchQ[a, <|_ -> _|>]
MatchQ[a, <|_|>]
```

give `False`. This is the behavior to be expected of atoms, so to modify an association with `ReplaceAll`, it looks like you are going to have use `Normal`.

```
Association[Normal[a] /. "a" -> "b"]
```

> `<|"b" -> 2|>`

Comment: A very nice explanation, +1

Comment: The tedious-looking workaround: `{<|8 -> 7|>, <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|>} /. a_Association /; KeyMemberQ[a, "a"] && a["a"] === "red" :> Nothing`. The last example can also be done with `KeyMap[]`: `KeyMap[# /. "a" -> "b" &, <|"a" -> 2|>]`.

Comment: I'll add that pattern-matching of this kind for `Association` is in active development internally.

Answer (score 7):

As of 10.4, there is now `KeyValuePattern`:

```
{<|8 -> 7|>, <|"a" -> "red", 6 -> 3|>} /. KeyValuePattern["a" -> "red"] :> Nothing
```

returns

```
{<|8 -> 7|>}
```

(The code reads a little weirdly - going by names alone, an Association shouldn't match a KeyValuePattern in my mind, because an Association isn't a key/value pair - but the intention is clear.)