# Building a replacement rule from a pattern, Assocation and RuleDelayed

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, associations

I'm trying to create a function that builds a replacement rule from a given pattern and I have trouble understanding what's going wrong.

*After having written most of the question, I see that it got quite long... For those who want to read the questions first, they're at the bottom. I have also come up with a workaround and possible explanation (I'll post a partial answer to this shortly), but I would still like to understand the issue at hand better.*

#### The goal

For this example, the goal is as follows: Given a patten `x_`, output `x_ :> <|1 -> x|>` (should work also for `y_`, etc.)

#### My approach

This here does the job just fine:

```
r1 = x_ /. p : Verbatim[Pattern][a_, _] :> p :> <|1 -> a|>
(* x_ :> Association[1 -> x] *)
```

Since I need it for later, let's `Evaluate` the r.h.s of the pattern:

```
r2 = x_ /. p : Verbatim[Pattern][a_, _] :> p :> Evaluate@<|1 -> a|>
(* x_ :> <|1 -> x|> *)
```

Notice the change from `Association[...]` to `<|...|>`.

#### The issue

Let's try out those rules on a simple example:

```
y /. r1
(* <|1 -> y|> *)

y /. r2
(* <|1 -> x|> *)
```

#### My attempts at an explanation

It seems something went wrong in the second case. Let's try to see how the two outputs differ:

```
e1 = Block[
    {$ContextPath = {"test`"}, $Context = "test`"},
  ToString@FullForm@(x_ /. p : Verbatim[Pattern][a_, _] :> p :> <|1 -> a|>)
  ]
(* "System`RuleDelayed[System`Pattern[Global`x, System`Blank[]], System`Association[System`Rule[1, Global`x]]]" *)

e2 = Block[
    {$ContextPath = {"test`"}, $Context = "test`"},
  ToString@FullForm@(x_ /. p : Verbatim[Pattern][a_, _] :> p :> Evaluate@<|1 -> a|>)
  ]
(* "System`RuleDelayed[System`Pattern[Global`x, System`Blank[]], System`Association[System`Rule[1, Global`x]]]" *)

e1 == e2   
(* True *)

r1 === r2
(* False *)
```

So, apparently, all symbols belong to the same contexts in both rules, but they're still somehow different. Another strange thing:

```
r2
r3 = x_ :> <|1 -> x|> (* using the output from the line above and prepending 'r3 = ' *)
(* x_ :> Association[1 -> x] *)

f /. r3
(* <|1 -> f|> *)
```

So simply reentering the output is enough to get it working.

## The questions

- What about `Association` is so special that the second approach fails? (As far as I can tell, it's at least not a scoping construct)
- How do I prevent this issue?
- For the future, how can I debug an issue like this? (i.e. how do I find out what's different between `r1` and `r2`)

Comment: similar: [(148074)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148074/142)

Comment: @WReach Thanks for the link - your answer there clears up the rest of my questions

Comment: @WReach Since your answer in the linked question also answers this question, should I close this as duplicate (since the answer is already given) or leave it and just link to that answer (since the question is arguably a different one)?

Comment: There does seem to be a lot of overlap.  I have registered a close vote and we shall see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question, I've come up with the following workaround:

```
r4 = x_ /. p : Verbatim[Pattern][a_, _] :>
       ((p :> Evaluate@HoldComplete[1 -> a]) /. HoldComplete -> Association)
(* x_ :> Association[1 -> x] *)

f /. r4
(* <|1 -> f|> *)
```

So as long as `RuleDelayed` does not see `Association`, everything is fine.

#### Update

@WReach pointed me to a clearer and more in-depth explanation of what's happening [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148095/36508). I think that answer covers everything from my questions.

#### My attempt at an explanation

It seems like as soon as the `Association[...]` expression is evaluated, it is replaced by an "atomic" object, that no longer allows `RuleDelayed` to "see" the values. (From [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119675/36508), we know that `Assocation`s have the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, but it seems it's more severe than that)

The confusion now arises since this "atomic object" is always displayed in it's `InputForm` (well, short of the `Association[...]` vs. `<|...|>` thing), and reentering this form consequently fixes the issue, as the `HoldRest` attribute of `RuleDelayed` prevents a new object from being created at this point.

The only point I can't answer at all is "how to tell the difference between the two outputs", and I'm hoping someone else can provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are complicating things by attempting to over specify the behavior.  Unless I have misunderstood your intent I believe the following will do.

```
ClearAll[patternReplaceRule]
patternReplaceRule[p : Verbatim[Pattern][s_, _]] := p :> <|1 -> s|>
```

Creating the rules

```
r1 = patternReplaceRule[x_]
```

> ```
> x_ :> Association[1 -> x]
> ```

```
r2 = patternReplaceRule[y_]
```

> ```
> y_ :> Association[1 -> y]
> ```

Applying the rules produce the expected result.

```
x /. # & /@ {r1, r2}
```

> ```
> {<|1 -> x|>, <|1 -> x|>}
> ```

```
y /. # & /@ {r1, r2}
```

> ```
> {<|1 -> y|>, <|1 -> y|>}
> ```

Also

```
r3 = patternReplaceRule[x_];
r1 == r3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the idea of using a `SetDelayed` rule to insert the pattern name into a held association - unfortunately I don't see how this can scale to my real use-case, which requires me to build an association out multiple individual matches. (i.e. find all `Pattern[...]` expressions in the input and build one association)

Comment: @Mathe172 You don't mention any of that in your question so how can you expect a solution that considers it?

Comment: Good point - I seem to have over simplified the problem when making the MWE, sorry for that. I hope my last comment didn't appear unthankful - even if I can't immediately apply it, your answer still helps to gain a deeper understanding of the underlying problem - so thanks again!