# Using Association[] in an Immediate Function

Tags: functions, associations, variable-definitions

I have an `Association[]` which is the result of an intensive computation. Its values include the variable `x` and I would like to turn the entire `Association[]` into a set of `Functions`.

I could use a `Delayed Definition` ([Reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)) using the `:=` function (`SetDelayed`). However, this would redo the initial computation every time, which is inefficient. I prefer using an `Immediate Definition` using `=` for the `Function`. However, that does not seem to work.

The following *Mathematica* code illustrates the problem:

```
f1[x_]=Association["linear"->x, "square"->x^2];
f1[3]["square"] (* x^2 *)
f2[x_]:=Association["linear"->x, "square"->x^2]
f2[3]["square"] (* 9 *)
```

Function *f1* does not produce the desired result, whereas *f2* does. How can I obtain the desired result? If possible, please explain the underlying theory, such that I will be able to tackle such problems myself in the future.

Comment: Would this do what you want? `as = Association["key" -> x]; f3[xx_] := as /. x -> xx`

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8831/9490) for the difference between definitions for your `f1` and `f2` functions.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, indeed it works. However, it feels a bit like a cheat. And I still don't understand why it does not work out-of-the-box.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for pointing to the nomenclature of `Set` and `SetDelayed`. However, I still don't get why `Association[]` needs a `SetDelayed` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: @LBogaardt See the documentation for `DownValues`.  Then look at the down values for your two approaches.
Btw, your goal is still unclear to me.  Mathematically, an association *is* a function.  Is your goal really just to produce a *new* association where you change what one of the keys maps to?  If so, why not just use `Association`, or if your prefer `AssociateTo` to modify the old association?

Comment: As to why it does not work "out-of-the-box", it has to do with the ambiguity between `Association` as constructor function and `Association` as head of an atomic association object.  See [(148074)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148074/142) for more discussion on this point.  The solution suggested by @MarcoB addresses this ambiguity directly.

Comment: @Alan I feel you are confused about my question and the desired answer. I have updated the problem, such that it, hopefully, becomes more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "why" has already been covered quite well by the previous answers, but the "how" could probably be expanded on a bit. If you want to be able to use syntax like `f1[3]["square"]` you could use `SubValues` instead:

```
f3[x_]["linear"] = x;
f3[x_]["square"] = x^2;

In[13]:= f3[2]["square"]

Out[13]= 4
```

Or just do `f3[x_, "linear"] = x;`, which is probably even easier. If you insist on having everything inside of an `Association`, I personally think the best way is to build an `Association` of `Function`s. I'm going to assume you start with some big expression with `x`es in it, so you need to convert that to a function of `x`:

```
In[21]:= f4 = Function[{x}, #] & /@ <|"linear" -> x, "square" -> x^2|>

Out[21]= <|"linear" -> Function[{x}, x], "square" -> Function[{x}, x^2]|>


In[22]:= f4["square"][3]

Out[22]= 9
```

As you can see, you now need to first specify the key before the value. The added bonus here is that (for purely numeric functions) you can substitute `Function` with `Compile` to get an extra boost in evaluation speed.

I'd also like to add that there's a good reason why you wouldn't want to do this in the way the OP asked for. If the syntax `f1[3]["linear"]` actually worked, it would still compute both `3` and `3^2` (and everything else you might have stored in the association) even though you only need the first key. Sure, the squaring might not be super intensive, but it's still extra work you're throwing away right afterwards. Both of the methods I proposed here avoid this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are encountering is related to the fact that [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) objects are atomic:

```
Association["key"->x] //AtomQ
```

> True

Since they are atomic, their contents can not be bound to a pattern variable. For a different example, consider:

```
(f[x_] = Graph[{1->2}, EdgeWeight->{x}, EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight"]) //InputForm
```

> Graph[{1, 2}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2]}, {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeWeight"}, EdgeWeight -> {x}}]

```
f[1] //InputForm
```

> Graph[{1, 2}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2]}, {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeWeight"}, EdgeWeight -> {x}}]

The [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) variant works because the [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) has not evaluated, so it is not yet atomic.

Comment: So a this point (with sparse arrays, associations, and datasets all being atomic), the notion of atomicity has shifted quite a bit from the early intuition for numbers, strings, and symbols.  Is that fair?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does this mean the only remaining option is the one by MarcoB, where the `Association` and its content are evaluated first and subsequently altered used a `Rule`? Quoting MarcoB: _as = Association["key" -> x]; f3[xx_] := as /. x -> xx_

Comment: @LBogaardt Can you provide an example where using SetDelayed causes an issue for you? There may be a better approach then switching to Set

Comment: @CarlWoll My specific use-case is not easy to explain briefly. Just imagine there are various functions which solve various differential equations. The solutions to each of these are stored in my `Association` under some key. Now, I would like to use them as a regular function (e.g. Plot), by choosing a key and then filling in the argument. But I do not want to solve the differential equation every time.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern-based function definition works by specifying rewrite rules.  These rules can be seen with the `DownValues` command.  When you use `Set` (`=`) the right-hand side is immediately evaluated.  In this case, the difference between your two functions is the difference in whether or not the right-hand side was evaluated in producing the rewrite rule.  So here is an equivalent way to define these two functions:

```
ClearAll[f1,f2,x]
DownValues[f1]= List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[f1[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]],Evaluate@Association[Rule["key",x]]]]
DownValues[f2]= List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[f2[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]],Association[Rule["key",x]]]]
f1[123]  (* <|"key" -> x|> *)
f2[123]  (* <|"key" -> 123|> *)
```

As you can see, the only difference is whether or not we forced evaluation of the association.

Comment: True, but this explains the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`. It does not address why `Associations` do not allow for a pattern variable (the `Atomic` reason by Carl Woll). In fact, change `Association` to `List` in your example, and the problem vanishes.

Comment: @LBogaardt Yes, atomicity is important.  So is the order of evaluation.  See the code in my answer: the two down values are identical except for the `Evaluate`.  I made no use of `SetDelayed`.

Comment: I think the effect is the same though. It would re-evaluate the `Association` every time. In my case, that's the computational bottleneck which I am trying to avoid. The answer by MarcoB solves this, though I am not 100% satisfied with the method.

Comment: @LBogaardt Can you explain your dissatisfaction?  If it is the reference to a global, you could close over that: `With[{as = Association["linear" -> x, "square" -> x^2]},
 f[xx_] := (as /. {x -> xx})
 ]`.  However, I would probably `g[xx_] := 
 Map[With[{x = xx}, #] &, Association["linear" -> x, "square" -> x^2]]`