# How to define a functional that produces at runtime a function by evaluating selected parts in its definition?

Tags: evaluation, associations

Consider the following functional as an example:

```
ClearAll[urlModifier];
urlModifier[url_]:=ReplaceAll[Function@Evaluate[
    Inactive[URLBuild][
        URLParse[url]/.{"slot"->Inactive[StringReplace][Slot[]," "->"_"]}
    ]
],{Inactive[x_]:>x}];
```

If I evaluate it using the following command:

```
urlModifier["https://www.somewebsite.com/path/slot"]["hello world!"]
```

It fails probably because the `Slot[]` is not aligning with the `Function`.

But if I do in-place evaluation of `urlModifier["https://www.somewebsite.com/path/slot"]` and use the result as input:

```
URLBuild[<|"Scheme"->"https","User"->None,"Domain"->"www.somewebsite.com","Port"->None,"Path"->{"","path",StringReplace[Slot[]," "->"_"]},"Query"->{},"Fragment"->None|>]&["hello world!"]
```

It works fine.

What should I do to `urlModifier` to make it accept the `Slot[]` for its `Function` that it creates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Summary**

The root cause of the surprising behaviour is that `Function` does not recognize `Slot[]` when it appears within an association *object* (as opposed to an association *constructor*).  To fix it, we must either "unwrap" the association object returned by `URLParse` or use a different approach altogether.

**The Problem: Association Objects vs. Association Constructors**

We can demonstrate the problem with a simpler example:

```
f = With[{assoc = <| "a" -> #1 |>}, assoc &]
(* <|"a" -> #1|> & *)
```

The function definition *looks* okay.  But it will not work:

```
f["hello world!"]
(* <|"a" -> #1|> *)
```

We can see the structural difference between an association constructor and an association object using `TreeForm`:

```
Function[<| "a" -> # |>] // TreeForm    (* constructor *)
```

[image: association constructor TreeForm]

```
Function[Evaluate[<| "a" -> # |>]] // TreeForm    (* object *)
```

[image: association object TreeForm]

More discussion on this distinction can be found in [(148095)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148095/142).  See the section labelled *Ambiguity of Association*.

**Fixing the Original Definition**

We can change the original definition to unwrap the association object during the initial evaluation and to recreate it upon use.  We do that using `Normal@URLParse[...]` and `Inactive[URLBuild@*Association]`.  The updated definition looks like this:

```
ClearAll[urlModifier];
urlModifier[url_]:=ReplaceAll[Function@Evaluate[
    Inactive[URLBuild@*Association][
        Normal@URLParse[url]/.{"slot"->Inactive[StringReplace][Slot[1]," "->"_"]}
    ]
],{Inactive[x_]:>x}];
```

... so then:

```
urlModifier["https://www.somewebsite.com/path/slot"]["hello world!"]

(* "https://www.somewebsite.com/path/hello_world%21" *)
```

**Alternative Definitions**

There are simpler ways to express this operation.

For example, we could define the `urlModifier` operator like this:

```
ClearAll[urlModifier]

urlModifier[url_] :=
  URLBuild[URLParse[url] /. {"slot" -> StringReplace[#, " "->"_"]}] &
```

We could also define it explicitly as a "curried form":

```
ClearAll[urlModifier]

urlModifier[url_][s_] :=
  URLBuild[URLParse[url] /. { "slot" -> StringReplace[s," "->"_"]}]
```

The `Function` form offers an advantage over the curried form in that, if desired, we could perform the initial URL-parsing at the moment of creation instead of every time the generated function is used:

```
ClearAll[urlModifier]

urlModifier[url_] :=
  With[{parsedUrl = URLParse[url]}
  , URLBuild[parsedUrl /. {"slot" -> StringReplace[#, " "->"_"]}] &
  ]
```

All of these definitions give the same results as the corrected original.

Comment: Thank you, I have been using this technique of function creation for sometime but was surprised why it failed here. Didn't know `Association` once created is an atomic expression, certainly doesn't appear like one. Looks like just a list with a different bracket form. Also use of `With` is nice to have the evaluation of required section happen outside the `Function` head and then gets placed inside requiring no need to change the `Evaluation` system of the language.

Answer (score 3):

```
fixspace = StringReplace[#, " " -> "_"] &;
slotfiller[url_] := StringTemplate[StringReplace[url, "slot" -> "``"]]
urlModifier02[url_] := URLBuild@URLParse@slotfiller[url][fixspace@#] &;
```