# Evaluated vs. unevaluated Association

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, associations, implementation-details, hold

This question might have a remote connection to my [older question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108948/7288), it is also about sameness of expressions and subtle differences observable only in certain forms.

I encountered this strange behavior:

```
a = Hold[<|1 -> 2|>]
(* Hold[Association[1 -> 2]] *)

b = Hold[Evaluate[<|1 -> 2|>]]
(* Hold[<|1 -> 2|>] *)

a === b
(* False *)

FullForm[a]
(* Hold[Association[Rule[1, 2]]] *)

FullForm[b]
(* Hold[Association[Rule[1, 2]]] *)

a[[1, 0]]
(* Association *)

b[[1, 0]]
(* Association *)

Uncompress[Compress[b]] === b
(* False *)

Uncompress[Compress[b]] === a
(* True *)

Print[Grid[{TreeForm /@ {a, b}}, Dividers -> All]]
```

[image: TreeForm]
What is going on here? What's the actual difference between `a` and `b`?

---

After I already started to write this question, I came up with more tests that might be more revealing:

```
MapAt[Hold, a, {1, Key[1]}]
(* MapAt::partw: Part {1,Key[1]} of Hold[Association[1->2]] does not exist. *)
(* MapAt[Hold, Hold[Association[1 -> 2]], {1, Key[1]}] *)

MapAt[Hold, b, {1, Key[1]}]
(* Hold[<|1 -> Hold[2]|>] *)

Depth[a]
(* 4 *)

Depth[b]
(* 3 *)

AssociateTo[a[[1]], 3 -> 4]
(* AssociateTo::invak: The argument Association[1->2] is not a valid Association. *)
(* AssociateTo[a[[1]], 3 -> 4] *)
```

So, it looks that `a` does not hold a real `Association`, but rather some kind of "raw" expression that can turn into a real `Association` when evaluated. For some reason, `FullForm` (which is supposed to be the most verbose) hides these details.

As a practical matter, I would like to be able to construct a `Hold` with a real `Association` inside, but whose values might be unevaluated expressions (wrapping each value in its own `Hold` is a possibility, but it would complicate matters).

Comment: related: [(46850)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46850/142), [(148095)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148095/142), [(203201)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203201/142)

Comment: An easy way to hold the contents of the `Association` is to use `RuleDelayed`. E.g. `<|1:>Print[1], 2:>Print[2]|>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Summary**

The confusion we observe here is largely due to ambiguous use of the symbol `Association` as an expression head.  On the one hand, `Association` can be used as a constructor function to build an association object.  On the other hand, it serves as the symbolic head of a constructed association object.  The difference between these two uses is normally hard to spot since the `FullForm` of a constructor expression is visually indistinguishable from the synthetic full-form of a constructed association object.  The two uses have different semantics, as observed in the question.

Many atomic types of Wolfram Language suffer from this same ambiguity.

**Discussion (current as of V12)**

Notwithstanding the ideal in Wolfram Language that [everything is an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), the basic [head-with-elements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html) composite expression is not always a good representation for some data types.  There might be efficiency issues or the representation might include details that are too distracting for the user to see.

The way to deal with such issues is to introduce new optimized types of expression to represent the challenging data types.  These optimized types are usually [atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46850/142), but some go so far as to fully simulate composite expressions (e.g. [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/142)).  These custom objects might be built into the kernel (e.g. associations or images) or they may be implemented in high-level WL code (e.g. datasets).  Either way, the internal subparts of these optimized types are generally not observable to the usual part access and pattern-matching facilities in the language.  Not observable, that is, unless the developer of the feature provided purpose-built functions to simulate such access.

Associations use of this kind of optimization.  The optimized object is a handle to a kernel-provided hash-trie implementation that offers both memory and speed advantages over an equivalent but unoptimized high-level expression.  `ByteArray` and `Image` are just two of many other examples of similarly motivated optimizations.

The constructor expression for an association is composite, but the produced object is atomic:

```
AtomQ[Unevaluated@<| 1 -> 2 |>]
(* False *)

AtomQ[<| 1 -> 2 |>]
(* True *)
```

The implementation of association provides a synthetic `FullForm` for these atoms:

```
<| 1 -> 2 |> // FullForm
(* Associaton[Rule[1, 2]] *)
```

... but the synthetic `Part` implementation does not match that synthetic `FullForm`:

```
Part[<| 1 -> 2 |>, 1]
(* 2, but if the full form were true then it should be 1 -> 2 *)
```

There are good practical reasons for this mismatch, but they can lull one into thinking that an `Association` atom is just a normal composite expression.

Associations are not unique with respect to such anomalies.  Almost all atomic optimizations of expressions involve mismatches of this kind.  What is more, the language does not enforce consistency -- it is up to the developer of each optimization to decide how fully to simulate basic expression behaviour.

Here are some things to watch out for:

- It is not possible to tell if an expression is atomic just by looking at its input form or even its full form.
- It is not possible to tell if an expression is optimized just by looking at its head.  Even though some constructor functions return an object with a different head (e.g. `Interpolation` -> `InterpolationFunction`), most do not (e.g. `Association` -> `Association`).  The design choice of using the same head for distinct expression types is an interesting one but will not be taken up in detail here.
- A strong clue that an expression has been optimized is that part access or pattern-matching gives surprising results.  For associations, the initial implementation did not support pattern-matching at all.  A simulation was added in later releases, but a scan of pattern-matching vs. association questions on this site will show that the simulation is not perfect.  Graph objects provide subelement access through purpose-built property functions and do not support the regular part and matching mechanisms.
- The input syntax and display forms of an optimized type may not be symmetric.  As examples, try examining the input forms of `Dataset[{1}]` or `Image[{{1}}]` or `ByteArray[{1}]`.
- The display forms of optimized expressions sometimes leave out critical information required to reconstitute the object's state (e.g. association examples from the question or copy-paste-evaluating a packed array's input form).
- The display forms of the unoptimized version of an optimized expression will generally not use short input syntax.  For example, `HoldForm[Complex[1, 2] // InputForm]` or similar expressions using `Rational` or `Association`.
- Atomic expressions can be written in high-level WL code using [SetNoEntry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61587/142).  Such expressions are opaque to most forms of pattern-matching (but not all).  Some built-in functionality use this (e.g. `Dataset`).
- When investigating the transition from unoptimized to optimized expression forms, beware that any evaluation will disturb the observations.  We must write expressions like `AtomQ[Unevaluated@...]`.  `TreeForm` in particular is known to have evaluation leaks that require doubling up constructions such as `Unevaluated` to see the actual structure (e.g. `TreeForm[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@<|1 -> 2|>]`).

Comment: This is an extremely insightful answer which clearly shows that the WL behaves in many respects like a natural language. Its grammer and syntax is not well defined, you have to learn it by trial and error and listening to expert speakers.

Comment: A very nice summary, +1. Just want to note that we have a number of subtle issues due to the (bad in my view) design choice of having the constructor use the same symbol as the actual built structure. For example, it creates problems for WXF deserialization (assocs that we get back need additional evaluation to internal structs), and some subtle scoping bugs, such as this `With[{assoc = <|"x" -> a|>}, Function @@ {a, assoc}][y]` returning `<|"x" -> a|>` instead of `<|"x" -> y|>`. Internal folks are well aware of these issues, but they seem to not be easily solvable in automatic way.

Comment: The insight that the constructor of a data structure and the head of the constructed data structure might have been different symbols — but just happened in this case to be the same due to a (maybe questionable) design decision — is very helpful to my understanding of this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Happy to help. To my mind, this single aspect of this story is really the crux of the matter, and is what is causing the biggest trouble (which prompted me to add this comment to an excellent answer above, which does contain this information but does not stress its importance to the degree I would do). Should constructor for such structures use a different head, and there would be no confusion - of course, with the understanding that the unevaluated constructor expression would not be `AssociationQ` any more (which I also think would've been correct).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I introduced an initial summary block, copying some text from one of my other posts on this subject to punch up the significance of the constructor/constructed ambiguity.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Do you think that `Uncompress @* Compress` should be an identity function under `SameQ`? Do you consider it a bug that it converts an evaluated atomic `Association` into a non-evaluated?

Comment: @WReach Thanks, this definitely makes it stand out.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov I'd say this is one of the issues that are hard to solve. Exactly the same problem is with WXF serialization / deserialization. Since presumably `Compress` does not hold internal state of the fully formed atomic object, the only choice one has is to serialize as an expression (constructor). But then when it comes back, it stays that way whenever it is inside some held expression.

Answer (score 8):

Associations are atomic ([`AtomQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html)).

Except for the most fundamental atomic types (such as `Integer`, `String`, `Symbol`, `Real`, etc.), most atoms have a representation as a compound expression<sup>1</sup>, which will normally immediately evaluate to a true atom. This is the difference between `a` and `b`: `b` contains a real association, while `a` contains its compound representation which is not actually an association, but would evaluate to one as soon as the `Hold` is removed. I wrote about this in more detail in two answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96225/12), and showed how to obtain the compound representation of an atom.

The reason why most atoms have a compound representation is so that they can be serialized (e.g. saved to an `.m` file, `Compress`ed, sent through MathLink, stored in a notebook, etc.) without each serialization method having to support each atomic type individually.

For most such atoms, there is a function to test their type. For associations, this is [`AssociationQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationQ.html). The patterns `_Association` and `_?AssociationQ` are not equivalent. The first one will match any compound expression with the head `Association`. The second one will only match true associations. There is also `GraphQ`, `ImageQ`, `MeshRegionQ`, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> Here I use the term "compound expression" to refer to an expression that has a head and multiple arguments in the form `head[arg1, arg2, ...]` accessible in the standard way, i.e. it is not an atom. Not to be confused with [`;`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html).

Comment: I find your wording "compound expression" unfortunate: Complex[1,2] looks like a (standard) expression, but evaluates to an atom. (Compound expressions are expressions concatenated by ;)

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch That's a good point. What would be a better term for "non-atoms"? Are you aware of a standard term? I can't find one in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

*Not a full answer, but too long for a comment.*

Please keep in mind that an `Association` is quite a complex data structure.  `Association`s are atomic, thus they behave quite differently from purely tree-based *Mathematica* expression. This is why the constituents of an `Association` cannot be accessed as we are used to do it with `Part`. (This has also to do with the fact that `Part` is overloaded for objects with head `Association`.)

The true data structure lives more on the "C-side" of *Mathematica*; it is not implemented in the top-level language (as far as I know).
A "true" `Association` consists of a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) along with various routines for accessing and modifying it. Think of it as a C++ class whose routines have been linked to *Mathematica* symbols. All that we can see of a true `Association` on the *Mathematica* side is basically what the developers *want* us to see. They tried their best to keep it as intuitive as possible. But of course it is impossible to completely hide the fact that `Association`s are no common *Mathematica* expressions.

`Hold` prevents building up this structure, so `Hold[<|1 -> 2|>]` will evaluate only to a real `Asssociation` when `Hold` is removed. So `Hold[<|1 -> 2|>]` is a merely tree-based expression and is displayed as such by `FullForm[Hold[<|1 -> 2|>]]`. In contrast, the `Evaluate` in `Hold[Evaluate[<|1 -> 2|>]]` causes the `Association` to be generated. And from that time on, `<|1 -> 2|>` is going to be atomic.

Comment: Constituents of associations can be accessed by Part, e.g. asoc[["key"]] gives the value associated with that key.

Comment: What I meant was that this causes an error: `Association[1 -> 2][[1, 2]]`.