# How to use ReplaceAll to create Association from List

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

I want to create a `List` of `Associations` from data in a two-dimensional `List` by using `ReplaceAll`, but did not manage to produce the expected result.

So here is a short example, the original lists are stored in the variable `values`:

```
values = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}
```

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}
> ```

and I want to transform this to a List of Associations with Keys "N" and "C" for the numbers and the characters

> ```
> {<|"N" -> 1, "C" -> a|>, <|"N" -> 2, "C" -> b|>, <|"N" -> 3, "C" -> c|>}
> ```

If I use the `ReplaceAll` command to create an Association I do not get the desired result

```
values /. {num_, char_} -> <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>
```

> ```
> {<|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>, <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>, <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>}
> ```

So the values for `num` and `char` are not considered correctly in `ReplaceAll`. However, If I would replace the `Association` by a `List` of `Rules` this works:

```
values /. {num_, char_} -> {"N" -> num, "C" -> char}
```

> ```
> {{"N" -> 1, "C" -> a}, {"N" -> 2, "C" -> b}, {"N" -> 3, "C" -> c}}
> ```

Is there any explanation why the behaviour is different for the Association? What is the usual way to create Associations from Lists?

Comment: Okay, I just found out that using `:>` (`RuleDelayed`) instead of `->` (`Rule`) in `ReplaceAll` does the trick. Is there any explanation why? So the working command is `values /. {num_, char_} :> <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use "Rule" the right side is evaluated at once resulting in:

```
{<|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>, <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>, <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>}
```

On the other hand, if you use [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html), the right side is only evaluated when the pattern has matched:

```
values = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}};
values /. {num_, char_} :> <|"N" -> num, "C" -> char|>
(*{<|"N" -> 1, "C" -> a|>, <|"N" -> 2, "C" -> b|>, <|"N" -> 3, "C" -> c|>} *)
```

Comment: But why is there no problem when using a List instead of an Association on the right hand side?

Comment: The reason is that Association has the attribute HoldAllComplete.

Comment: I don't think that is true, after all `HoldComplete` also has that attribute yet `n` is substituted in `1 /. n_ -> HoldComplete[n]`.  I believe the cause is the fact that association constructor expressions evaluate to atomic association objects (see [Evaluated vs. unevaluated Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204254/142)).

Comment: Thank's. There is always new to learn..