# Replacement of Association value does not evaluate

Tags: replacement, associations

```
Cos[a - b] /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}
```

gives 1

However,

```
<|1 -> Cos[a - b]|> /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}
```

gives

```
<|1 -> Cos[0 - 0]|>
```

The `Cos[0 - 0]` does not evaluate.

Even `FullSimplify` doesn't help

```
<|1 -> Cos[a - b]|> /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}// FullSimplify
```

still gives

```
<|1 -> Cos[0 - 0]|>
```

How to make the `Association` expression after replacement evaluated directly(Not shift+Enter)?

Comment: Oh, I solve this just now. //Normal//Association. So this post needs no answer now :)

Comment: Or you can pass the replacement rule inside: `<|1 -> Cos[a - b] /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}|>`

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Thank you for comment. But replacement rule outside is more useful :)

Comment: Yes, of course. I can appreciate that. I just mentioned it in case that the expression of interest was not too long. Still, applying `Normal` is far more elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once an [association construction expression has been evaluated into an atom](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204296/142), the keys and values of the resulting atom are kept in held form.  That is, they are not reevaluated after subsequent replacement rules have been applied.

There are various work-arounds.

**Operate upon the Unevaluated Association Construction Expression**

If the application permits it, performing the replacement before evaluating the association into an atom is a possibility:

```
Unevaluated@<|1 -> Cos[a - b]|> /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}
(* <|1 -> 1|> *)
```

But beware that this strategy will also affect the keys, something that does not normally happen when using `ReplaceAll` with association atoms:

```
<| a -> a |> /. a -> 1
(* <| a -> 1 |> *)

Unevaluated@<| a -> a |> /. a -> 1
(* <| 1 -> 1 |> *)
```

**Operate upon the evaluated Association Atom**

If we must work with an evaluated `Association` atom, then we can use `Map[ReplaceAll[...]]` to force reevaluation of replaced values:

```
$expr = <| Sin[a - b] -> Cos[a - b] |>;
$rules = {a -> 0, b -> 0};

$expr // Map[ReplaceAll[$rules]]
(* <| Sin[a - b] -> 1 |> *)
```

As noted before, such replacements only affect the values.  Should we want affect both the keys and values, then we must use `AssociationMap`:

```
$expr // AssociationMap[ReplaceAll[$rules]]
(* <| 0 -> 1 |> *)
```

Should we wish to perform the replacement upon only a specific key of the association, we can use `MapAt`:

```
<| x -> Cos[a - b], y -> Cos[a - b] |> //
  MapAt[ReplaceAll[{a -> 0, b -> 0}], #, Key[x]] &

(* <| x -> 1, y -> Cos[a - b] |> *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for valuable information on Association and solutions :)