# Problem with Association in DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic, core-language

How can I understand the success of the first append but the failure of the second, here? (Mma 13.3.) Is there a ready work around?

```
DynamicModule[{g = 0.05},
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[g], ContinuousAction -> False],
  Append[List[], Dynamic[g]],
  Append[Association[], "test" -> Dynamic[g]]}
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Wrap `Dynamic` around the "construction" of the `Association`:

```
DynamicModule[
 {g = 0.05},
 {
  Manipulator[Dynamic[g], ContinuousAction -> False],
  Append[List[], Dynamic[g]],
  Dynamic@Append[Association[], "test" -> Dynamic[g]]
  }
 ]
```

`Manipulate` effectively does something along these lines (in fact it wraps `Dynamic` around everything), which is why it works while your `DynamicModule` doesn't.

The reason it fails without the `Dynamic` is a bit involved, but essentially it boils down to the fact that `Association`s, once constructed, keep their contents unevaluated/protected in some sense (see e.g. [this question & related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263842/replacement-of-association-value-does-not-evaluate)). This means that e.g. `Module` localization doesn't work within constructed associations (something similar to the following is happening inside `DynamicModule`):

```
<|a -> b|> /. x_ :> Module @@ Hold[{b = 2}, x]
(* <|a -> b|> *)

{a -> b} /. x_ :> Module @@ Hold[{b = 2}, x]
(* {a -> 2} *)
```

Note how the `b` in the first example has not been replaced by 2 like one might expect. Wrapping `Dynamic` around the association constructions delays said construction until after `DynamicModule` has done its job and has localized all the variables.

Comment: Thanks, that provides some basic guidance, but there are still many mysteries. For example, is it the case that multiple instances of DynamicModule in a single notebook cell will (surprisingly!) share variables? For example, if a single cell has `DynamicModule[{g = 0.05}, {Append[Association[], 
   "test" -> Dynamic[g]], 
  Manipulator[Dynamic[g], ContinuousAction -> False]}]`
and also `DynamicModule[{g = 
   0.05}, {Append[Association[], "test" -> Dynamic[g]]  Manipulator[
    Dynamic[g], ContinuousAction -> False]}]` (note the missing comma), moving the latter slider affects the fomer!?

Comment: Note how the second slider is inside the association (since the value of the association is effectively being "multiplied" by the slider) - this means that the sliders `Dynamic[g]`, as well as the `Dynamic[g]` occurrences of the associations of both `DynamicModule` expressions are inside an association (after the expressions have been evaluated at least): As a result, the localization fails as outlined above, and the `g` that is being manipulated/displayed is not the one from a `DynamicModule`, but rather the global variable `g` (you can check this by evaluating `g` in a separate cell)

Answer (score 2):

Does this what you want?

```
Manipulate[{Append[List[], g], 
  Append[Association[], "test" -> g]}, {{g, 0.05}, 0, 0.1}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False
 ]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Note, "DynamicModule" is comparable to "Module". And "Manipulator" can be used inside "Module" or "DynamicModule"  E.g. with "DynamicModule" you get:

```
DynamicModule[{g = 0.05}, {Append[List[], Dynamic[g]], 
   Append[Association[], "test" -> Dynamic[g]]} Manipulator[
   Dynamic[g], ContinuousAction -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to use `DynamicModule` in another setting and I need to understand its behavior. I suppose the difference in behavior is some kind of clue ...