# Why is Evaluate not handle on the Association?

Tags: evaluation

This is a demo code

```
r = {1, 2, 3};

fs1 = Table[
    Function[t, 
        Evaluate@{"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[r[[i]], t]}],    
      {i, 3}]; 

fs2 = Table[
    Function[t, 
        Evaluate@<|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[r[[i]], t]|>],    
      {i, 3}];
```

`fs1[[2]]["hi"]` outputs `{"arg" -> "hi", "diff" -> f[2, "hi"]}`, however `fs2[[2]]["hi"]` outputs `<|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[2, t]|>`

Comment: Probably related to the fact that an evaluated association is 'constructed' and atomic. See `asso = <|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> 2 t|>; asso /. t -> 1` for example. That is not enough to explain why  `Function[t, Evaluate@<|1 -> t|>]@2` does not work though.

Comment: `Attributes[Association]` contains `HoldAllComplete`.

Comment: @tueda yes but `Function[t, Evaluate@HoldComplete[t]]@2` still injects the argument.

Comment: @Kuba you are right, now I'm confused by the difference of `Function[t, Evaluate@Association[1 -> t]]@2` and `Function[t, Evaluate@HoldComplete[1 -> t]]@2`...

Comment: @tueda HoldAllComplete is not enough but being atomic only is not enough either: `Function[t, Evaluate@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> t, 3]][2]`. Interesting.

Comment: Related: [Evaluated vs. unevaluated Assocation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204254/142), [Pattern matching Association in rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148074/142)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can use `Table[With[{ri = r[[i]]}, Function[t, <|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[ri, t]|>]], {i, 3}]` to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) is atomic. Since [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) is also [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete), let's examine an atomic object that is not [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete).

```
Clear[x]
g = Graph[{x->1}];
g //AtomQ
g //InputForm
```

> True

> Graph[{x, 1}, {DirectedEdge[x, 1]}]

Now, give `x` a value:

```
x = 2;
g //InputForm
```

> Graph[{x, 1}, {DirectedEdge[x, 1]}]

Notice that `x` has not changed inside of the [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) object. This is exactly what is happening in your example.

Comment: I agree with the diagnosis but SparseArray is atomic as well yet: `Function[t, Evaluate@SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> t, 3]][2] // InputForm`.

Comment: To me it is a confusing design to have atomic "objects" which do not look like there are atomic (in the sense that they have no subparts).

Answer (score 0):

It must be clearly a bug, because `(ToExpression@ToString@fs2[[2]])[hi]` works correctly.
Moreover,

```
On[Assert];
Assert[fs2[[2]] == Function[t, <|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[2, t]|>]]
```

gives:

```
Assert::asrttf: Assertion test fs2[[2]]==Function[t,Association[arg->t,diff->f[2,t]]] evaluated to Function[t,<|arg->t,diff->f[2,t]|>]==Function[t,Association[arg->t,diff->f[2,t]]] 
that is neither True nor False.
```

while `Assert[fs1[[2]] == Function[t, {"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[2, t]}]]` succeedes.

Also it is definitely Not an issue with atomicity:

```
fs1 = Table[Function[t, {"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[r[[i]], t]}], {i, 1, 3}]
fs2 = Table[Function[t, <|"arg" -> t, "diff" -> f[r[[i]], t]|>], {i, 1, 3}]

fs1[[2]][hi]
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
{"arg" -> hi, "diff" -> f[{1, 2, 3}[[i]], hi]}

fs2[[2]][hi]
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
<|"arg" -> hi, "diff" -> f[{1, 2, 3}[[i]], hi]|>

fs1[[2]] // AtomQ
False
fs2[[2]] // AtomQ
False
```

w/o `Evaluate` or if you replace `r[[i]]` with `r[[2]]` both fs1 and fs2 succeede to replace `t` with `hi`.

Comment: With ToString/ToExpression the association is destroyed and constructed again and with the latter stage it can have values injected inside.

Comment: @Kuba no, it is not injected, because if you just type the output of `Evaluate` by hand: `fs3 ={Function[t,<|"arg"->t,"diff"->f[1,t]|>],Function[t,<|"arg"->t,"diff"->f[2,t]|>],Function[t,<|"arg"->t,"diff"->f[3,t]|>]}` and then call it `fs3[[2]][hi]` you will get the correct return value `<|arg->hi,diff->f[2,hi]|>` .  So it's obviously someting wrong is going on inside the VM of WL or whatever they call it.

Comment: Your 'by hand' example, without `Evaluate` has associations before construction, and they are not constructed before function injects `t` because `Fuction` is `HoldAll`. Then they are constructed and atomic but `t` is already replaced. This is confusing because constructed and not associations look the same as explained in a topic linked in comments. What I meant earlier is that associations constructed (forced by Evaluate) will be destroyed with `ToString` and ToExpression will create a function again, but without Evaluate so it will indeed 'work'