# Pattern matching in Association fails in `Set` assignment

Tags: associations, hold, memoization

I want to define a symbolic-valued function using `Set` to memoize the result. However, I get different results when using an `Association` and a `List`:

```
f1[x_] =  (Pause[3];{"a"->1,"b"->x})
f2[x_] := (Pause[3];{"a"->1,"b"->x})
g1[x_] =  (Pause[3];Association@@{"a"->1,"b"->x})
g2[x_] := (Pause[3];Association@@{"a"->1,"b"->x})
```

When running these functions, only `f1` and `f2` produce the correct result, and only `f1` memoizes the result, only requiring one computation involving a `Pause` (here standing in for a more expensive computation).

```
In[2]:= f1[y]
Out[2]= {"a" -> 1, "b" -> y} 

In[3]:= f2[y]
Out[3]= {"a" -> 1, "b" -> y} (* long computation *)

In[4]:= g1[y]
Out[4]= <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> x|> (* incorrect *)

In[5]:= g1[y]
Out[5]= <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> x|> (* incorrect; long computation *)
```

Looking at the [common pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119542/81775) question, one finds that `Association`s were atomic in Mathematica™ 10.4. I am currently using version 13, and it appears that `AtomQ@Association == True` still. I suspect this is causing the issue I am working with.

As Mathematica™'s built-in dictionary data structure, I first attempted to use it to build a class-like object one can build easily in other languages. Building getters and setters with `Association`s is relatively easy, but now function definitions are getting complicated.

Am I better off using lists of rules to get around this issue, or is there a workaround I can use, perhaps with `Replace[expr,x->#]&` or something to that effect?

Comment: It is simply bad practice to define functions using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` - end of story.  Use `g2` as you have written it, not `g1`.

Comment: I think that last was meant to be `g2[y]` and not a repeat of `g1[y]`.

Comment: @Phro - you haven't made it clear what the actual problem you are trying to solve is, and so you have users guessing and giving answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're running into the issue described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148095/36508). To work around it, you can try something like the following:

```
(g[x_] := Association[#]) &[
 (Pause[3]; {"a" -> 1, "b" -> x})
 ]

g[2]
(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> *)
```

Effectively, we are pre-computing the result without the `Association` wrapper, and create a `SetDelayed` rule that only converts it into an association before returning. This keeps the `x` visible to `SetDelayed`, while still pre-computing everything else.

An alternative that also supports nested associations is to use a dummy symbol:

```
(g[x_] := With[{association = Association}, #]) &[
 (Pause[3]; 
  association["a" -> 1, "b" -> x, "c" -> association["d" -> x^2]])
 ]

g[2]
(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> <|"d" -> 4|>|> *)
```

Here, we replace the dummy symbol `association` with `Association` before returning the result. I used `With` above, but `ReplaceAll` and similar should also work

Comment: How is this different from `g[x_] := Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> x]`?  I don't understand what problem this solves

Comment: @JasonB. I interpreted the question as being about the case where `{"a" -> 1, "b" -> x}` (i.e. the content of the association) is slow to compute, hence the attempt in the question to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` - I might be wrong though

Comment: This addresses my question, but not quite my use-case, which involves nested associations. (say `..."b"-><|"b1"->x, "b2"->x^2|>...|>`). Is it better to post this follow-up as a separate question?

Comment: @Phro See the update

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see any memoization going on here. To get it memoized, the typical pattern looks like this:

```
g11[x_] := g11[x] = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> x|>
```

or to mimic your complex calculation

```
g11[x_] := (Pause[3]; g11[x] = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> x|>)
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: The memoization I am looking for is not about caching the values of the function for its various inputs, but caching the expression (itself a function of the inputs) so future substitution runs quickly.

Comment: Hmm. Then why don't you just pre-compute it? Since the example you've given shows no dependency between the actual function definition and this expensive precomputation, it's difficult to understand what the problem is here.

Comment: In practice, the computation is indeed coupled with the input variables, though only so far as playing the role of indices. In this way, I wish to run the computation to end up with a function whose only role is to substitute in the values of said indices.